# Can we choose to view other people's posts sorted by "latest" or "most popular" on Facebook, like on Twitter?

Tags: facebook

Facebook seems to choose to show you what it thinks are "hottest", but can you choose to view friends' and groups' posts sorted by "latest"?

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, you can choose to see  Most Recent posts on you News Feed.

From [Facebook Help Center](https://www.facebook.com/help/218728138156311?helpref=faq_content):

> By default, News Feed shows the most popular posts first. To temporarily view stories by most recent:
>
> 1. Click **Home** at the top of Facebook.
> 2. Hover over the News Feed tab in the left side menu and click on three dot (...) .
> 3. Select **Most Recent**.
>
> Learn the difference between viewing News Feed by [top stories and most recent](https://www.facebook.com/help/1036754746376685?helpref=faq_content).

You can view posts by most recent, but News Feed will eventually return to its default setting.